# Magento2 custom redirection is not working

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, redirect, redirect-url

I tried below code but page is not redirecting

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$redirect = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http');
$redirect->setRedirect('Your path....');
```

Please, anyone help me.

Comment: what issue your are facing ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define constructor for it.

Below code is working for me.

> Vendor/Package/Model/Plugin/Form.php

```
<?php 
namespace Vendor\AdvancedReviews\Model\Plugin;

class Form
{
protected $_responseFactory;
protected $_url;

public function __construct(

    \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
) {
    $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
    $this->_url = $url;
}



public function afterexecute(\Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Group\Save $save,$result)
{
           // Do your stuff
}

$CustomRedirectionUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('*/*/');
    $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($CustomRedirectionUrl)->sendResponse();
    exit();
```

Comment: It's not working. I need redirect is working .phtml file ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing custom redirection from Controller, you can use the below code:

```
$url = $this->_url->getUrl('customer/account/create'); //custom path URL
$this->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
return;
```

If you want to do custom redirection using object manager, you can use the below code:

```
$response = $this->_objectManager->get("\Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface");
$url = $this->_objectManager->get("\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface");

$url = $this->_url->getUrl('customer/account/create'); //custom path URL
$response->setRedirect($url);
return;
```

Comment: what is _url? i get error Undefined property